# phpMyAdmin: Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I get this error message on the phpMyAdmin login page:

- phpMyAdmin: Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please check your PHP configuration.

Does someone knows the reason for it?

Thanks, Udo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the mcrypt add-on for php is not installed.

Try logging in and running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I expect the first command will install the missing package. The second command restarts apache so that the mcrypt add-on is activated.

If you get a message that php5-mcrypt is already installed we'll have to do some more digging.

Comment: I get..... sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: @Elliot what OS are you on? You may not have apt-get